# how to compare values in loop in python

Tags: python, django

how can i compare values in a loop? i just want to compare all the values if who is the smallest (minimum) value using loop.

this is my code:

```
>>> c = Product.objects.filter(client=1).values('id')
>>> c
[{'id': 2}, {'id': 1}, {'id':5}, {'id':8}]
>>> for x in c:
...  price = ProdPrice.objects.filter(product=x['id']).aggregate(Min('price'))['price__min']
...  print price
... 
1000.0
1050.0
900.0
3000.0
>>>
```

in my code, i just want to compare all the `products` and print only the smallest/minimum `price` using loop.

i just want to print is `900.0` the smallest price of all the products.

thus anyone have an idea about my situation?

thanks in advance ...

Comment: If you want to find the smallest value, then say you want to find the smallest value. Expecting to need a loop is only an assumption on your part. Also, I have no idea what this is supposed to do with django...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `min` function.

```
min(ProdPrice.objects.filter(product=x['id']).aggregate(Min('price'))['price__min'] for x in c)
```